# Why - is not used in the command 'tar -xvfz'

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ tar -xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz 
tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The following command works:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz
```

I have referred to the manual of tar and still cannot figure out why I cannot use -xvfz in the above case.

Thank you

Comment: Not a programming question. Try http://askubuntu.com or http://s.tk/unix.

Comment: Tar is not ubuntu only, but linux, unix, mac-OS - even DOS/Windows are reported to have tar-applications. It would therefore fit to Superuser.

Comment: Probably a parser glitch, with the - version being interpreted much differently (thinking 'z' is the archive file to work on, and xampp-... is a file to extract from the archive).

Answer (score 3):

The error you received is because the f has to be immediately before the filename of the archive.  -f is for "file"

tar -xvzf xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz should work.

tar -xvfz xammp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz is attempting to load the file z.

As for why it works without the dash, I'm not sure.